# how to delete duplicates in a snowflake table but keeping only one record? Anyway other than inserting into another table using rownumber()?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried using row_number() to select the records having row_number as 1 and inserted into separate table. Is there any other method on deleting from the same table without using another table?

Comment: Create a view and group by or distinct the table ... then rename the view to look like the table ?   Alternatively hash(*) to get dups and hash(* , rownum() ) to predicate the delete statement ?

Comment: Clone the original table, remove dupes from new table as Adrian suggested, rename original table e.g. ".._OLD", then rename new table to have same name as original table.

Comment: @Adrian White can you please elaborate on second approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried the hash approach but snowflake didn't work ... here's an alternative just replace the table with select distinct * from table!

Step 1 - create some sample data (ideally anonymous would have supplied this)

```
create or replace table arr_base(account_id varchar, account_name varchar, activity_date date, arr number(32,4));

insert into arr_base (account_id, account_name, activity_date, arr)
values
 ('A','ACCOUNT A','2021-01-31',50)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2021-01-31',40)
,('A','ACCOUNT A','2020-01-31',40)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2020-01-31', 35)
,('C','ACCOUNT C','2020-01-31', 30)
,('D','ACCOUNT D','2020-01-31', 33)
, ('A','ACCOUNT A','2021-01-31',50)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2021-01-31',40)
,('A','ACCOUNT A','2020-01-31',40)
,('B','ACCOUNT B','2020-01-31', 35)
,('C','ACCOUNT C','2020-01-31', 30)
,('D','ACCOUNT D','2020-01-31', 30);
```

Step 2 - Validate table

[image]

Step 3 -

```
create or replace table arr_base as select distinct * from arr_base
```

[image]

Comment: replace table arr_base as select distinct * from arr_base didnt work in snowflake

Comment: create or replace table arr_base as (select distinct * from arr_base)  works fine for me ... are you using snowflake?